# sum from UNION in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have below simple table

```
FROM_CATEGORY      TO_CATEGORY      LENGTH
     A                 D              5
     B                 C              6
     B                 B              2
     C                 D              4
     D                 D              1
```

I just want to get below result

```
CATEGORY      COUNT_REPEATED      SUM_LENGTH
   A                1                5
   B                2                8
   C                2                10
   D                2                10
```

I have tried to use below query but for the pair ( B  B ) and pair (D D ) I will count and sum two times

```
SELECT t1.CATEGORY , COUNT(*) , SUM(t1.LENGTH)  FROM
(SELECT   FROM_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY , SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH FROM categoryTable GROUP BY FROM_CATEGORY
UNION ALL 
SELECT   TO_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY, SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH   FROM categoryTable GROUP BY TO_CATEGORY) AS t1 GROUP BY t1.CATEGORY
```

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 1):

Simply filter those rows where both categories are the same:

```
SELECT t1.CATEGORY , COUNT(*) , SUM(t1.LENGTH)
FROM
 ( SELECT   FROM_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY , SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH 
   FROM categoryTable
   WHERE FROM_CATEGORY <> TO_CATEGORY 
   GROUP BY FROM_CATEGORY

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT   TO_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY, SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH
   FROM categoryTable
   GROUP BY TO_CATEGORY) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.CATEGORY
```

Edit:

Based on your comment you want to include the rows where both `FROM_CATEGORY`and `TO_CATEGORY` are the same in your count, but not in the sum. Then you need to move the WHERE-condition into a CASE and do *conditional aggregation*:

```
SELECT t1.CATEGORY , Count(*) , Sum(t1.LENGTH)
FROM
 ( SELECT   FROM_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY ,
      Sum(CASE WHEN  FROM_CATEGORY <> TO_CATEGORY THEN LENGTH ELSE 0 end) AS LENGTH 
   FROM categoryTable
   GROUP BY FROM_CATEGORY

   UNION ALL 

   SELECT   TO_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY, Sum(LENGTH) AS LENGTH
   FROM categoryTable
   GROUP BY TO_CATEGORY) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.CATEGORY
```

Comment: thanks for that , but the count   it should be exist in every select statement same like sum(length).

Comment: @AliAlawi: I don't get what you mean. The `count(*)` in the outer Select should include the rows where `FROM_CATEGORY = TO_CATEGORY`?

Answer (score 1):

modified dnoeth's answer as below

```
SELECT t1.CATEGORY , SUM(t1.counter), SUM(t1.LENGTH) FROM 
( SELECT   FROM_CATEGORY  AS CATEGORY , COUNT(*)  AS counter , SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH FROM categoryTable 
WHERE  FROM_CATEGORY  <> TO_CATEGORY 
GROUP BY FROM_CATEGORY
UNION ALL 
SELECT   TO_CATEGORY AS CATEGORY, COUNT(*)  AS counter , SUM(LENGTH) AS LENGTH  FROM categoryTable GROUP BY TO_CATEGORY) AS t1
GROUP BY t1.CATEGORY
```